# How to use watir-webdriver to wait for page load

Tags: webdriver, watir, firewatir, safariwatir

Using [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver), how do I wait for a page to load after I click a link?

At the moment I am using:

```
sleep n
```

But this is not ideal as the page response varies so much.

Is there a way to test whether the page is ready or whether there is a certain element in the page? I understand in the normal Watir gem there is `Watir::Waiter.wait_until` or something similar, but I don't see this in the webdriver version.

Comment: Are you trying to make something wait until after the page is fully loaded?  I thought that was standard behavior...

Comment: Actually you are correct. However the reason I am having to sleep is because I have some ajax updating the page content. I want to wait until the response is successful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if they're the best way, but this is how I'm handling this for waiting for an updating `div` to clear:

```
while browser.div(:id=>"updating_div").visible? do sleep 1 end
```

This is how I handle waiting for something to display:

```
until browser.div(:id=>"some_div").exists? do sleep 1 end
```

Comment: cool this works perfectly in firefox, not so great in chrome.

i've gone with:

    sleep 1 until browser.div(:foo => 'bar').exists?

Comment: The above method is not recommended because it may never return and lock up your scripts (javascript error, code change, etc.).  

Watir::Waiter.wait_until(15) { browser.div(:id => "updating_div).visible? }

Answer (score 7):

Today's release adds an optional require that brings in some helpers for waiting for elements. These are not (at the moment) available in Watir 1.6, so be aware if you use both libraries side by side.

Check "[AJAX and waiting for elements](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/AJAX-and-waiting-for-elements)" in the Watir-webdriver Wiki for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The best summary is found in "[Waiting](http://watir.com/guides/waiting/)".

This is it in a nutshell:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').wait_until_present
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').when_present.set 'your name'
b.button(:value => 'Submit').click
b.button(:value => 'Submit').wait_while_present
Watir::Wait.until { b.text.include? 'Thank you' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`browser.wait_until` can be used.

It's more helpful because you can define what to wait for in the parameters (`()`), as in:

```
browser.wait_until(browser.text.include("some text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I wait for AJAX in my project:

```
ajax_loader = $b.element(:xpath  => "//*[@id='spinner-modal-transparent' and @aria-hidden='true']/div/div/div/div/img[@alt='Ajax transparent loader']")

if ajax_loader.exists?
  ajax_loader.wait_while_present(timeout=350)
else
  puts "The AJAX loader was not present."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wait_until` or `waituntilExists` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I tried to fix it by combining `wait_until_present` and

```
until browser.div(:id=>"some_div").exists? do sleep 1 end
```

tricks povided by @marc:

```
some_div = browser.div(:id => 'some_div')

begin 

  Watir::Wait.until
    some_div.visible?
  end

rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError

  until some_div.visible?
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

Notice that it is your own responsibility to make sure that

```
div(:id => "some_div")
```

does exist.